# Get token price on BSC with solidity

Tags: function, solidity

I need to find the price pair of some token on BSC

i already found some code on reddit to find the price pair on uniswap, i know pancakeswap is a fork of uniswap so i thought it was good but it doesn't work

I imported in my smart contract IBEP20.sol and IpancakeswapV2Pair.sol

this is my code:

```
    function getTokenPrice(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint)
   {
    IPancakeswapV2Pair pair = IPancakeswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
    IBEP20 token1 = IBEP20(pair.token1());
    (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();

    // decimals
    uint res0 = Res0*(10**token1.decimals());
    return((amount*res0)/Res1); // return amount of token0 needed to buy token1
   }
```

always returns 0

Comment: Is your contract deployed on the same network (i.e. testnet or mainnet) as the pair contract? What is the pair contract address, and the `amount` value when you're calling the `getTokenPrice()` function?

Comment: I tried the contract on the mainnet, the pair address I tried is this: 0x5f66f543B20A4BD4195521C14E9ae77ED7111c98
the amount mean "how many tokens1 do I have to pay to take * amount * of token0?"